# What are artlangs?

Tags: terminology

I often hear the term *artlang* applied to some conlangs (e.g. Toki Pona). What does it mean? How would I determine if a conlang I am creating is an artlang? What are some examples of artlangs?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_language), an artlang is a conlang made to be aesthetically pleasing or to be part of a piece of literature. Some notable artlangs include Toki Pona, Quenya, and Klingon. Klingon was created to be part of a work of literature, specifically Star Trek. Quenya was created as part of Tolkien's Middle-Earth worldbuilding project. Toki Pona was an experiement in minimalism and the conclusions of the Sapir-Whorf hypothesis.

Comment: About Quenya, per Tolkien, the "‘stories' were made rather to provide a world for the languages than the reverse. To me a name comes first and the story follows".

Comment: And yet many characters' names changed.